# The validity of some transformation of law of large numbers

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Given the law of large numbers, for the i.i.d random variables $X_1,X_2...X_N$,
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} (X_1+X_2...X_N)=\mu$$

where $\mu$ is the mean of $X_i$.

I am here to ask whether the following statement is valid?
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}  X_1+X_2...X_N=N\mu$$

Thank you!

Comment: Of course not, the left-hand side doesn't depend on $N$ while the right-hand side does.

Comment: If $\mu$ is positive then $\displaystyle \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}  X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_N$ is infinite, with a corresponding result for negative $\mu$.  If $\mu = 0$ and there is a positive probability $X_i$ is not $0$ then there is no limiting value to the series.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the points in the comments, you are missing a key issue about sums of iid r.vs:

Let $0<Var(X)=\sigma^2<\infty$, then:

$$Var(\bar X)=O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

but

$$Var(n\bar X)=O(n)$$

So, as the commenters have pointed out, your conjectured limit diverges *almost surely*